# How can I export and use embedded mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm struggling to export and use the embedded document Progress. 
If I where to export it in the same way as UserSchema the I can fill it,
but the I cant fill the UserSchema... 
What is the correct way to use and export the embedded document?

```
var Progress = new mongoose.Schema({
    something : {
        type: String
    }
});

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index:true
    },
    progress : [Progress]

});
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

And this in file.js:

```
var User = require('../models/user');
var something = req.body.something;
var curUser = req.user;
var newProgress = new User({
    something: something
});
User.createProgress(curUser, newProgress, function(err, progress){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log("Progress: " + progress);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I can just write:

```
var newProgress = ({
    something: something
});
```

instead of:

```
var newProgress = new User({
    something: something
});
```

Then when I pass it to the createProgress I can use push there